# Woocommerce order status for coinpayments.net always defaults to 'Cancelled', how to force 'On-Hold'

Tags: woocommerce, coinpayments-api

We use [coinpayments.net](https://www.coinpayments.net) on our relatively busy WooCommerce store as a method of cryptocurrency payment.

Unfortunately the developers don't provide a way to change the default order status to anything other than `'Cancelled'`. Well I tell a lie, they let you change it to `'Processing'` but they also warn against doing so because this will make all orders look as if they have been paid when they haven't. The easy option would be to let us pick our own status then, but oh well...

Can someone help with `functions.php` code to make the order status go to `'On-Hold'` until we verify the payment has processed?

What these orders currently do:

```
Pending Payment -> Cancelled
```

What we need:

```
Pending Payment -> On-Hold
```

What we do **not** want:

```
Pending Payment -> Cancelled -> On-Hold
```

Thank you so much for your help, this will save us from an endless number of emails from customers wondering why their orders are showing as cancelled even though they sent their payments correctly!

**EDIT:**

After waiting a couple of days for some help on here, we decided to give up on CoinPayments for WooCommerce. We switched to Coinbase Commerce for WooCommerce instead. Thanks.

Comment: As this is related to a third party plugin behavior, the only "unclean" way *(avoiding customer notification for cancelled status)* seems to go through the plugin code and change this behavior until they allow you with a hook to change the status as you want…

Comment: I suppose the difficult part is understanding the code well enough to be able to change it. Unfortunately none of us understand it at all. 

Thanks for your input :)